# How does TCP SYN port scan method work on UDP ports?

Tags: port, scanning, nmap

If I've understood correctly, most common port scanning method is using TCP Syns and waiting for an ack packet from each port.

How does it work when a port only receives UDP packets? (UDP DNS servers, for instance)
Will the port answer as well?

Another minor question:
Why, when port scanning 8.8.8.8, I see that 53 is a TCP DNS port and not UDP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DNS requires TCP if the response is > 512 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! Know anything about the first question?

Comment: Maybe lazy firewalls that don't discriminate between packet types?

Comment: Perhaps, but this method should work in high rates.

Answer (score 2):

> How does it work when a port only receives UDP packets? (UDP DNS
>   servers, for instance) Will the port answer as well?

Not necessarily. If you probe a UDP port, it might not answer because

1. a packet filter drops your packet
2. the service does not understand the probe and thus does not bother to answer
3. the service is not willing to answer to packets from arbitrary IP addresses

In all of these cases nmap's verdict ist `open|filtered`. Since UDP has no handshake like TCP, there is no reliable way to tell `open` apart from `filtered`; see also [Port Scanning Basics](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) in the official Nmap Reference Guide.

Answer (score 0):

> How does TCP SYN port scan method work on UDP ports?

It doesn't.

You can't send a TCP packet to a UDP port.